# Accessing functions for custom Haskell data types

Tags: haskell, types

I have searched and searched for the following, in stack overflow in particular and Google in general. My abject apologies if it is either already covered or so trivial as not to be mentioned anywhere.

I have defined a custom data type for objects that are sometimes discrete and sometimes continuous, like so:

```
data Gene =  Discrete String Int | Continuous String Double 
                 deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)
```

Here, the String represents the name of the Gene (e.g. vWF or some such) and the numerical parameter is its state, either discrete or continuous, like so:

```
bober = Discrete "vWF" 2
slick = Continuous "gurg" 0.45432
```

I could use record syntax to access the properties of a Gene, but then there are 2 different functions for name and state. What I would like is one function to access identity, and one to access state. For identity, this is straightforward, since that is a string for both value constructors:

```
geneName :: Gene -> String
geneName (Discrete dName _) = dName
geneName (Continuous cName _) = cName
```

When I try to make a function that return the state of a Gene though, I run into trouble. I thought pattern matching would work:

```
geneState :: Num a => Gene -> a
geneState (Discrete _ dState) = dState
geneState (Continuous _ cState) = cState
```

This fails to load in GHCi, giving:

> DynamicalModularity.hs:34:35:
>      Couldn't match type `Int' with`Double'
>      Expected type: a
>        Actual type: Double
>      In the expression: cState
>      In an equation for `geneState':
>          geneState (Continuous _ cState) = cState
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

I tried using `case` syntax:

```
geneState :: Num a => Gene -> a
geneState gene = case gene of (Discrete _ dState) -> dState
                              (Continuous _ cState) -> cState
```

Again this doesn't load:

> DynamicalModularity.hs:30:56:
>      Couldn't match type `Int' with`Double'
>      Expected type: a
>        Actual type: Double
>      In the expression: cState
>      In a case alternative: (Continuous _ cState) -> cState
>      In the expression:
>        case gene of {
>          (Discrete _ dState) -> dState
>          (Continuous _ cState) -> cState }
>   Failed, modules loaded: none.

My question is: Is what I want to do possible and/or good Haskell? Am I missing something obvious? I have been searching for a solution for some time now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you anticipate using `geneState`?

Comment: Maybe you think `Num a => Gene -> a` means "this function returns some kind of number, depending on a `Gene` value we feed it". It does not. There is no such thing in Haskell.

Comment: There is such a thing in GHC Haskell (existentials) but I'd want to understand the problem better before recommending them.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Existentials are most probably wrong here. You can do very little with a simple existential type like `data Number = forall a. (Num a) => Number a`.

Comment: Returning an existentially-quantified `Num` instance is pretty useless. You can..  Call `negate`, `abs`, and `signum`. Nothing of value there.

Comment: @Carl You can add a constant...

Comment: However any of `Real`, `Fractional` and `Floating` might turn out to be worthwhile here (or even things like `Show`, `Eq`). It all depends on what the O.P. wants - most likely it would be best for callers just to pattern-match directly on `Gene`.

Comment: Why not return a value of the type you really want to represent? This is a choice between two types, Int and Double, so just return Either Int Double. Don't complicate things more than you need to.

Comment: @bheklilr There is very little difference between `Either Int Double` and `Gene` (just a string), so... why not just return your input? :P

Comment: @n.m. Because Either is an instance of Bifunctor, so you can work with it easier

Comment: If you think Bifunctors are the answer for a beginner, I'll be proposing existentials more vigorously :-)

Comment: You can't have `geneState :: Num a => Gene -> a` but you can have `geneState :: Fractional a => Gene -> a` : `geneState (Discrete _ i) = fromRational (toRational i); geneState (Continuous _ i) = fromRational (toRational i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any code which would consume the result of calling `geneState` would need to be able to handle both `Int` and `Double`—clearly this is the case because I can call `geneState` on both discrete and continuous values.

Let's represent the part of this code which consumes the `Int` and the `Double` separately. Both of these parts must be simple functions so we can write them as

```
intConsumer    :: Int    -> result
doubleConsumer :: Double -> result
```

Now I have both of these parts return the same result because the consuming code must always return the same kind of thing regardless of whether it receives a discrete or a continuous `Gene`.

Now, we can write `geneState` using this information and pattern matching

```
geneState :: (Int -> result) -> (Double -> result) -> Gene -> result
geneState intConsumer doubleConsumer (Discrete   _ st) = intConsumer    st
geneState intConsumer doubleConsumer (Continuous _ st) = doubleConsumer st
```

---

One way we might simplify this function is to assume that all of our consumers function on `Double`s alone—even if the input `Gene` was discrete. This is mathematically justifiable because `Double` contains all of the `Int`egers (which can be made more formal if you want).

In Haskell the function `fromIntegral` converts `Int`s to other numeric types. We can thus write

```
geneStateAsDouble :: Gene -> Double
geneStateAsDouble = geneState fromIntegral id
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is just the church representation of `Either` and a forgetful map from `Gene` to `Either`.

Comment: Thank you. Your response got me thinking more about what will consume the result of this function. It is the case that the modeling behind the code will be entirely different in the continuous case, so the consumer will produce something different also, which means that I probably should have different accessor functions for each, or even abandon the idea of continuous and discrete genes under the same type entirely.